# Bundle .js files in app folder in Angular 6 build

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

I want to add main.js,pollyfill.js etc in app folder how do I create an app folder inside dist folder.I am new to this kindly suggest how to make changes for the same
Sharing the angular.json  snippet for reference,

```
  {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "merchandising": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.css", "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css", "src/style.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations":{}
          }
        },

      }
    },
 }}
```